# Variables within loop needed for if, else if, else statement, not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

*Updated combining loops, simplifying some code, still not working.*

The for loops are supposed to be going through particular columns in my sheet (data[n][0] and data[n][0]data[n][1]) and check if a name or email is in it already. If either appear, fan will be set to "isOldFan". (this is all within another big loop, and the first thing that happens is both vars are set to "new" to start out)

The if, else if, else action should be determined by the status fan. Unfortunately, regardless of factors, every time it is skipping to the else and unstarring and archiving every email.

I've tested the loops by themselves, and the individual parts of the if, else if, else stuff, and they seem to work in parts...

```
// customer name or email on master sheet?
for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
  var sheetName = data[n][0];
  var sheetEmail = data[n][1];
  if ((sheetName===fanName) || (sheetEmail===fanEmail)) {
    fan = "isOldFan";
  }
}

// the magic
if (dueDate === today) {
  if(fan==="isOldFan"){
    // existing fan unstar and archive
    GmailApp.unstarMessage(orderEmail);
    GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(uncheckedOrderEmails[e]); 
  }else if(orderTotal > 70){
    // new VIP adds to sheet with "VIP"
    GmailApp.unstarMessage(orderEmail);
    ss.appendRow([fanName, fanEmail, restaurantName, "VIP"]);       
  }else{
    // new fan, add to sheet
    ss.appendRow([fanName, fanEmail, restaurantName]);
    GmailApp.unstarMessage(orderEmail);
    GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(uncheckedOrderEmails[e]);
  }
}
```

I've left out the parts of this giant loop that this is within that parses each email in the box. At the start of the big loop (before each new email to check) fan is set back to "old".

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong here, so maybe the problem is in the rest of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

*Off Topic.* I don't see any errors either, but you can simplify this code a bit:

```
if (dueDate === today) {
    var isOldFan = data.some(row => row[0]===fanName || row[1]===fanEmail);

    if(isOldFan){
        // existing fan unstar and archive
        GmailApp.unstarMessage(orderEmail);
        GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(uncheckedOrderEmails[e]); 
    }else if(orderTotal > 70){
         // new VIP adds to sheet with "VIP"
        GmailApp.unstarMessage(orderEmail);
        ss.appendRow([fanName, fanEmail, restaurantName, "VIP"]);       
    }else{
        // new fan, add to sheet
        ss.appendRow([fanName, fanEmail, restaurantName]);
        GmailApp.unstarMessage(orderEmail);
        GmailApp.moveThreadToArchive(uncheckedOrderEmails[e]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. There aren't errors, it's simply not catching the if or else if when it should have.
Apologies, I guess I didn't put enough information , but var data is actually an array of everything in that column of the sheet, column [0] their name, column [1] is email.
Good call on the simpler way to write that, though, thanks.